Get User By Email - Not Working with Variables (PHP)
I'm trying to return user data based on an email input, code is simply:
$email = 'abcde@gmail.com';
$user = get_user_by( 'email', $email );

This returns nothing and when I try filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) it tells me that the email isn't valid.
When I hard code the email into the function it retrieves the information correctly:
$user = get_user_by( 'email', 'abcde@gmail.com' );

What am I doing wrong in the first code snippet?

I have try to check this and it is working fine as you can check in an attached screenshot https://ibb.co/CvBk4Ww
The issue may be with the data type so could you please try var_dump($email) so it's data type can be checked, also if possible please share whole code so I can check this.
